# Can't get modules in /lib/modules loaded during startup

Tags: kernel, drivers, arm

I used to have an Ubuntu installed in an ARM (32 b). The drivers needed to run the system were copied in the folder "/lib/modules" and loaded during the startup.

Due to a hardware update, I have recently moved to a new Ubuntu for an ARM aarch64 (ubuntu-base-16.04.6-base-arm64, downloaded from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/16.04/release/)), that is, an Ubuntu minimal. I need the drivers to be loaded during startup as they were in the previous version, but in this last version, the folder "/lib/modules" doesn't exist by default. I've created it and added the modules, but now the drivers are not loaded (even after installing acpi).

I can load them with modprobe, but there are a lot of them and not all are required. Which is the suitable way to make the modules placed in "/lib/modules" automatically loadable during the startup?

Comment: Are they kernel modules? Is there a directory called `/usr/lib/modules-load.d`?

Comment: Yes, but it is empty (I've checked in the previous version and it was empty as well).

Comment: And yes, they are kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in `conf` files in `/etc/modules-load.d`. Modules specified in those files in that directory are loaded at boot.

For example, create a file in that directory with this name:

```
module.conf
```

Within the file, put the following:

```
#loads module
module
```

Replace `module` with the actual name of the module. You can put them all into one `conf` file or make one for each of the modules that you want to load at boot.